# DOM representation of an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm just writing some code to traverse the DOM for a table, and I got a surprise. The DOM (in FF, at least) isn't what I'd expected. FF has inserted a `tbody` and various text nodes, which just contain a "\n". The source HTML is:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th></th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>Mar</th><th>Apr</th><th>May</th><th>Jun</th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Oct</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dec</th>
</tr>
<tr><th>2010</th>
<td id='tdid0'>53</td>   <td id='tdid1'>249</td>  <td id='tdid2'>1689</td>  <td id='tdid3'>22753</td>
<td id='tdid4'>23051</td><td id='tdid5'>23633</td><td id='tdid6'>23923</td> <td id='tdid7'>23306</td>
<td id='tdid8'>23943</td><td id='tdid9'>24196</td><td id='tdid10'>24440</td><td id='tdid11'>24156</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>2011</th>
<td id='tdid12'>24262</td><td id='tdid13'>22554</td><td id='tdid14'>25507</td><td id='tdid15'>23144</td>
<td id='tdid16'>24354</td><td id='tdid17'>24610</td><td id='tdid18'>24870</td><td id='tdid19'>24424</td>
<td id='tdid20'>24698</td><td id='tdid21'>22640</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

1 - FF has inserted a `tbody` as the first child of the `table`, so I have to go up 3 levels (from a `td`) to find the `table`, not 2

2 - The html view in Firebug shows 3 rows, as expected, where rows 2 and 3 have a `th` followed by 12 `td`s. However, when single-stepping through, it turns out that the `tbody` has 6 children, with a NL text node after each row

3 - Firebug claims that each row has 13 children, as expected (a header and 12 data items). when stepping through the children with `nextSibling`, though, it turns out that the expected `th` and `td` elements are actually separated by text nodes, containing WS.
Any idea what's going on? Can the browser basically do what it wants? Thanks.

Comment: It was proved that the worse case is when the "webdevelopers" can do what they want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> FF has inserted a tbody

In HTML 4 a tr element may not be a child of a table element. You need a tbody, thead or tfoot element in between. The start *and* end tags of a tbody element are optional though. Firefox is correctly inserting it.

> it turns out that the tbody has 6 children, with a NL text node after each row

You have white space there in your markup

> it turns out that the expected th and td elements are actually separated by text nodes, containing WS

Ditto

Comment: On the WS - I thought it was just ignored in html? It seems that FF has not only preserved it, but explicitly inserted it into the DOM - does this make sense?

Comment: It is collapsed, not ignored.